# SocketTimeOutException while sending a HttpPost request

Tags: android, http, request, apache-httpclient-4.x

My application works with Facebook and does post requests with JSON params.
Request is sent for ~ 7-8 minutes and then I catch a SocketTimeOutException.
In 10 minutes I can send a request again.

Here's the code:

```
public static String httpTPRequest(String url, String params) {
    String response = Static.EMPTY;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, HTTP_TIMEOUT);

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.log(TAG, "tp server request:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return response;
}
```

Why it happens?

Stack trace

```
SocketTimeoutException:Http::Socket stack:org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:131)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:247)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:535)
Http::Socket stack: java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1054)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:129)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
Http::Socket stack: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
Http::Socket stack: com.saymeow.saymeow.utils.Http.httpTPRequest(Http.java:194)
Http::Socket stack: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
Http::Socket stack: com.saymeow.saymeow.requests.ApiRequest$1.run(ApiRequest.java:83)
Http::SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected
```

Comment: Please add the Stacktrace of the SocketTimeOutException

Comment: What does your url look like?
What does params look like?

Maybe Facebook isn't answering. 
Can you try to make the same request manually with curl?

Comment: I use this code not only for facebook. My url is http://api.verumnets.ru/?v=1 and params are {"data":"limit":40},"service":"feedInbox"}

Comment: Are you sure api.verumnets.ru is the right hostname? Even Googles name server won't resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

If params is a JSON-String you might have to replace:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
```

with

```
httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(params.getBytes("UTF8")));
```

Comment: Unfortunately i catch Exception

Comment: Which Exception do you catch?

Comment: I have add stack trace of SocketTimeoutException